# Regex Expressions in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm confused on how regex works in scheme for when I need to detect a `-` seperated by two digits.

```
#px"[[:digit:]]-"
```

is how I would find a digit followed by `-`, but I get errors when I try to do

```
#px"[[:digit:]-[:digit:]]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Character classes are surrounded by two square brackets on each side. In your second expression, you only have one square bracket on each of the inner sides of the character classes. You need to do this instead:

```
#px"[[:digit:]]-[[:digit:]]"
```

On the other hand, using full POSIX character classes just to match digits is a little verbose. Since it's so common, you can just just use the `\d` to match a digit instead. Just remember to escape the backslash as well:

```
#px"\\d-\\d"
```

Comment: This answers the question as-asked, and I up-voted. Having said that, I more commonly see (and prefer) `#px"\\d-\\d"`. (Like the POSIX `[[:digit:]]`, `\\d` works only with `#px` not `#rx`.)

Comment: @GregHendershott I considered that as well, and I thought of mentioning it, but I didn't have time when I initially wrote this answer. I'll edit it in, though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks so much!  It's working out great.  Just as an side, how would I go about just replacing the - so "5-5" becomes "5@5", using regexp-replace or something like that?

Comment: @user879559 You should probably take a look at [clusters](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/regexp-clusters.html?q=regexp). If you need more help, feel free to ask another question, but you can probably figure it out from there.